# Blender will not import all of my custom shortcuts. How do I fix this?

Tags: import

I recently changed some of the shortcuts to make Blender more comfortable for me, but every time I export my key configuration & import it into Blender (on another computer) some of the custom shortcuts work & others do not. I'm very confused & tired of remapping them over & over again.

Comment: are you using the same OS?

Comment: care to upload your key configuration file so we can study it?